# On Windows, why java -version return Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, java, environment-variables

1. I've removed all ancient Java 8 install on my computer.
2. I've downloaded latest openjdk 11 from https://jdk.java.net/11/ and extracted the content to `C:\Program Files\Java\`.
3. I've setup system environment variable to

   ```
   JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
   ```

   and added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to Path.
4. In a command prompt `> java -version` returns:

   ```
   Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
   Error: could not find java.dll
   Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
   ```
5. Why?

Answer (score 59):

How to make it work:

Windows > Start > cmd >

```
C:> for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

or

```
C:> where java
```

It returns `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` folder which contain:

- java.exe
- javaw.exe
- javaws.exe

Browse to this folder with Windows file explorer and remove everything (three files above).

Close and reopen cmd (Windows > Start > cmd >)

```
C:> java -version
```

Should now return:

> openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

or something similar depending on which java release package you've downloaded...

It works!

Comment: Thanks! The above steps fixed the error I was getting. Then to finish the clean-up, I deleted the C:\ProgramData\Oracle folder since it didn't contain anything else useful to me. I also removed C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath from my system PATH environment variable where Oracle had left it as the first entry.

Answer (score 3):

I came across same issue,

how to check:

1. open cmd, execute "where java" (without quote)
2. you should see more than one output of the java path, one of it should be the one you set "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin", the other ones should be in above

how to solve:

## option 1:

simply delete all the other java path

## option 2:

check your enviroment variable setting, move your %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the above all the other java path

Comment: How do I "simply delete all the other java path" ? Or "move your %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the above all the other java path" ?

Comment: for Windows by “edit system environment”

Answer (score -2):

Try Adding the new Java home path at the start of the path instead of end i.e %JAVA_HOME%\bin;(rest of path). It will get picked first. Worked for me.